# Expression.Constant discarding existing WHERE conditions when applied to IQueryable<T>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

#### Context

I have an IQueryable extension method `GetAllGroupedBy` that is supposed to solve the greatest-n-per-group problem on MySQL via EF Core.

Basically it constructs this type

```cs
public struct OrderedGroupItem<TModel, TKey>
{
    public TKey GroupKey { get; set; }
    public int OrderKey { get; set; }
    public TModel Value { get; set; }
}
```

internally by counting, for each element in the table, how many elements are below that element in any given order.

The code is 100 lines long and can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/RNN6UL7C).

#### Problem

When the `IQueryable<T>` query is passed in the extension method, the debugger shows:

```
value(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[Persistence.Models.Project])
        .Where(...)
```

because the extensions method is called like this:

```cs
query.Where(...).GetAllGroupedBy(...);
```

so the `query` passed in correctly stores the `Where(...)` part previous to the `GetAllGroupedBy` call.

But when I then put it inside the expression via `Expression.Constant(query)` the resulting expression is:

```
{
    new OrderedGroupItem`2() 
    {
        GroupKey = Invoke(x => x.GroupKey, x), 
        OrderKey = value(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[Type])
            .Where(y => 
                (Invoke(x => x.GroupKey, x) 
                    == Invoke(x => x.GroupKey, y))
            )
            .Where(y => 
                Invoke((x, y) => 
                    (
                        (Compare(x.OrderValue, y.OrderValue) < 0) 
                        OrElse (
                            (Compare(x.OrderValue, y.OrderValue) == 0) 
                            AndAlso (x.Id < y.Id)
                        )
                    ), 
                    x, 
                    y
                )
            ).Count(), 
        Value = x
    }
}
```

and the translated SQL doesn't repeat the original `.Where(...)` filters.

#### Question

Why does `Expression.Constant(queryable)` remove the `.Where(...)` conditions stored in the queryable? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```cs
Expression.Constant(query)
```

you should use:

```cs
query.Expression
```